# EventListener change manual change not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an eventlistener for an html element **X** that will hide some other elements whenever **X**'s value changes.

I have another function that will change **X**'s value. However when this function executes and changes **X**'s value the eventlistener change doesnt trigger.

In this case **X** is "sa_placement_type". And this elements value is changed with the first event listener below.

```
document.getElementById("form_1").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var changed_id = e.target.id,
        changed_type = e.target.type,
        changed_value = e.target.value,
        target_id,
        target_ele;

    if (changed_id.endsWith("_preview")) {
        target_id = changed_id.substring(0, changed_id.length - 8),
        target_ele = document.getElementById(target_id);

        /*This is where the elements value is changed, should trigger event listener below.*/
        target_ele.value = changed_value;
    }

});

document.getElementById("sa_placement_type").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var sa_type = document.getElementById("sa_placement_type"),
        wrapper_percent = document.getElementById("div_placement_percent"),
        wrapper_flatfee = document.getElementById("div_placement_flatfee");

    if (sa_type.value == 'PercentageFee') {
        wrapper_percent.style.display = 'block';
        wrapper_flatfee.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (sa_type.value == 'FlatFee') {
        wrapper_percent.style.display = 'none';
         wrapper_flatfee.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML and make this an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The `change` event only occurs when the value is changed by the user, not when it's changed by Javascript.

Comment: Yeah I created a function to manually just call and update on that element. So it works, but I kind of feel dirty because I'll probably have to add more manual functions for similar cases....Is there any other alternative way to detect variable changes via JS?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript